# ruby markdown processor that does footnotes?

Tags: ruby, markdown, footnotes

Do any of the maintained decent ruby markdown processors do an extension for footnotes? I know some markdown processors in other languages do (although I'm not sure which ones).

The ruby ones aren't so great at documenting what markdown extensions they might support.  (Heck, neither are the ones in other languages).

anyone know?

Comment: IIRC [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html) does, although I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org), and it's my library of choice for markdown. It actually provides a superset of Markdown syntax, borrowing additional functionality from other libraries. For example, the footnote capability was borrowed from [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#footnotes) package.

Example syntax:

```
That's some text with a footnote.[^1]

[^1]: And that's the footnote.
```